# How to use SharePoint search query with SharePoint Granular access permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

We have an Azure function that queries/creates/updates SPO DocumentLibraries.  We earlier had 'Sites.ReadWrite.All' and 'Files.ReadWrite.All' permission to the Azure function service-prinicpal (SP), and as part of best practices switched it to 'Sites.Selected' permission.  With this new configuration the creates/updates are working, however the SharePoint search query api's (_api/search/query) is failing.  Doesn't the 'Sites.Selected' configuration work for search query api's?  Is provisioning 'Sites.Read.All' only available alternative? (Which makes the app less secure).

**Note**:  The search query is limited to specific documentLibraries by using path filter, these are configured as part of 'Sites.Selected' configuration.

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='*+AND+(Path:"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE1/RECORDS" OR Path:"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE2/RECORDS")'&trimDuplicates=false&selectProperties='Column1,Column2'&refiners='Column1OWSTEXT'&refinementFilters='Column1:equals(\"xxxxx\")'&rowLimit=5
```

Updated 21/02:  With 'sites.Selected' the search queries are throwing 'unauthorized exception'.

Comment: What error message is returned from the search query?

Comment: @CallumCrowley: Missed most important info; the search queries fail with 'Unauthorized exception' - i have updated the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the app have access to the root site where your query is being sent?

Answer (score 0):

Sites.ReadWrite.All and Files.ReadWrite.All permissions are tenant-level permissions.
Sites.Selected - site level permission.
I'm not sure if Sites.Selected app permissions would allow search queries, but
I'd ensure first that your app has Sites.Selected permissions to 3 sites -

- https://tenant.sharepoint.com/
- https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE1
- https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE2

If the app has Sites.Selected permissions to the root site (https://tenant.sharepoint.com/) - that does not mean the app has access to all tenant sites.

Anyway, if providing Sites.Selected access to the root site is not possible - consider using two separate queries:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITEname1/_api/search/query?querytext='*+AND+Path:"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITEname1/RECORDS"'&trimDuplicates=false&selectProperties='Column1,Column2'&refiners='Column1OWSTEXT'&refinementFilters='Column1:equals(\"xxxxx\")'&rowLimit=5

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITEname2/_api/search/query?querytext='*+AND+Path:"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITEname2/RECORDS"'&trimDuplicates=false&selectProperties='Column1,Column2'&refiners='Column1OWSTEXT'&refinementFilters='Column1:equals(\"xxxxx\")'&rowLimit=5
```

[Search content with application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-searchall)

[Providing Permissions to a Site for Sites.Selected App](https://vladilen.com/software/microsoft-365/providing-permissions-for-sites-selected-app/)