# Is that 'Sites. Selected' permissions level allows the SharePoint online global search?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, azure-functions

Is that 'Sites. Selected' permissions level allows the SharePoint online global search?.

My query is:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='*+AND+(Path:"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITEname1/RECORDS" OR Path:"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE2/RECORDS")'&trimDuplicates=false&selectProperties='Column1,Column2'&refiners='Column1OWSTEXT'&refinementFilters='Column1:equals(\"xxxxx\")'&rowLimit=5
```

or any comments over this question?

[How to use SharePoint search query with SharePoint Granular access permissions?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-to-use-sharepoint-search-query-with-sharepoint-granular-access-permissions?newreg=dbcbb62ae019481c9a864f537ecd0faf)

Comment: Your query is being sent to the root site, have you granted the app permission to the root site?

Comment: yes @CallumCrowley my application granted with root level permissions, i.e. https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE2

write permissions to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<SITE2-Site_CollectionId>/permissions

Comment: No, I'm referring to the actual root site for your tenant e.g. https://tenant.sharepoint.com, not https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site2

Comment: @CallumCrowley by giving the access to tenant.sharepoint.com will ignore the purpose of sites.selected permission, we intentionally wants to give granular permissions to specific sites, can this be achive by giving permissions specific site.

Comment: tenant.sharepoint.com is a specific site, just the root site. Giving access to the site at tenant.sharepoint.com doesn't give access to all sites. You're running a search request against the root site of your SharePoint tenant

Comment: Have tried by giving permissions to tenant but search api not works , again getting unauthorize error

Comment: Have you tried running the search query from the site you have granted access before? e.g. https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site2/api/search

Comment: Even this URL throwing 400 response , how ever when I try in browser it is working fine.
Below error I'm getting 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: No User or App Context found

And this error seems, indicating lack of permissions Sites.Read
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/855706/csom-microsoft-sharepoint-client-serverexception-n

Comment: Any suggestion @CallumCrowley ?

Comment: Might be best raising this on the SP dev GitHub issues: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues